# Simple fields Wordpress plugin should have multiple group selection at a time

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

If you are familiar with WordPress plugin then It might be a quite easy task:
I am using Simple field WordPress plugin ..its quite fine for me ..But what I need is multiple checks of a group at a time from the selection of groups..

Like when you have install the plugin it asks to make a group and then you can make fields accordingly ..
so on your post you will see a section for selecting a group and only of those group fields will be shown.What I need to select two groups at a time from there..

Here is the plugin site:http://simple-fields.com/

Thanks!
NItz

Comment: How can I get multiple group selection at a time on a single post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to add the same group again, or is it a completely different group you want to add?

If it's another group then you can add that group to your post connector, and then both groups will be visible when you use that post connector.

Comment: Actually I have made two groups ..and I want to select both groups at a time .As an example on a single post I want to show both groups ..like I have made two groups named as SINGLE and MULTI and both having different fields ..so I want to put my information on both groups field.. as a summary multiple selections of group at a time on a single post.    Hope you understand!!Please help me

Comment: Ok, as I understand it:

 * you have created two different field groups
 * you want to show both these field groups on the same page?

The solution would then be:

 * create a new post connector
 * add both your field groups to this connector
 * use the connector on your post

Would/does that work?

Comment: You are the boss!! this is the thing I was about to do..Can you please tell me one more thing..as of now I have made multiple entries in both sections..How can I call them on my template ..what query should be fired?

Comment: I have got the solution from your documentation...this is pretty good man!